# SQL select first character following each occurrence of a specific character in string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a string containing the first character of a string and the first character following each occurrence of a specific character in the string. For example if '.' is the specific character, 'Hello.Bye.Today.Yesterday' should return 'HBTY'.

What I have so far:

```
SELECT substring(Hello.Bye.Today.Yesterday, 1,1)
```

Comment: What code do you have already?

Comment: First, this is not a SQLish task, so a database is not the optimal tool.  Second, you need to tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: if you know `split` in c#

Comment: If you want to do this in SQL, you will have to write your own function I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use SQL for this, create a function with the following logic

```
DECLARE @value VARCHAR(255)
SET @value = 'Hello.Bye.Today.Yesterday'

DECLARE @result VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @curChar CHAR(1)

DECLARE @start INT, @end INT
SET @start = 2
SET @end = LEN(@value)

SET @result = SUBSTRING(@value, 1,1)

WHILE @start < @end
BEGIN
    SET @curChar = SUBSTRING(@value, @start, 1)
    IF @curChar = '.'
    BEGIN
        SET @result = @result + SUBSTRING(@value, @start + 1, 1)
        SET @start = @start + 1
    END
    SET @start = @start + 1
END
```

Result

```
HBTY
```

Answer (score 0):

If your database supports the INSTR() function, this will work. But, as Gordon Linoff pointed out, there are limits to this type of activity in relational databases. As you see, you must hard-wire:

- the very first character
- each possible occurrence of '.'; the first, the second, the third ...

Not so easy ...

```
-- use '+' instead of '||' in SQL Server
WITH 
input(s) AS (SELECT 'Hello.Bye.Today.Yesterday') 
SELECT
    SUBSTR(s,1,1)
  ||SUBSTR(s,INSTR(s,'.',1,1)+1,1)
  ||SUBSTR(s,INSTR(s,'.',1,2)+1,1)
  ||SUBSTR(s,INSTR(s,'.',1,3)+1,1)
  AS the_string
FROM input;
the_string
HBTY
```

So you have an exceptional behaviour for the first character to concatenate; then, you have to stop going `SUBSTR(s,INSTR(s,'.',1,<n>)+1,1)` at the right point in time, so you have to know in advance how often '.' occurs in the string.
Let's see what happens if we go one past the end:

```
WITH 
input(s) AS (SELECT 'Hello.Bye.Today.Yesterday') 
SELECT
    SUBSTR(s,1,1)
  ||SUBSTR(s,INSTR(s,'.',1,1)+1,1)
  ||SUBSTR(s,INSTR(s,'.',1,2)+1,1)
  ||SUBSTR(s,INSTR(s,'.',1,3)+1,1)
  ||SUBSTR(s,INSTR(s,'.',1,4)+1,1) -- there is no 4th '.'
  ||SUBSTR(s,INSTR(s,'.',1,5)+1,1) -- there is no 5th '.'
  AS the_string
FROM input;

the_string
HBTYHH
```

So INSTR() returns 0 , then, and you get the first character of the string each time. You would have to "decorate" your code with CASE WHEN expressions in that case to catch that....